# Index/Matching Multiple Line Items on to One Page with Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, indexing, match

I've got a price list [Data] with up to a thousand multiple items from numerous suppliers. These are output regularly from a database to be sorted (by supplier) for easy updating of pricing and other assorted tasks.
The search criteria are selected from a list box created from the [Data].
This is then to be matched to all the line items in the [Data] and a [Catalogue] created, returning multiple cells from each line. A lot of cells on each row need to be ignored in order to re-enter the system correctly.

I've got it creating a list so far however, the matching starts at the first supplier item and continues to the end of the list, as though it doesn't match the items following after that first initial match.

It needs to pick out only the data from the selected supplier and return the required results.
The raw data is not sorted by supplier, and I am hoping to be able to do this without doing a data sort first. But even with a data sort, it runs to the end of the list.

```
Private Sub SupplierData_Click()
    ListBoxValue = SupplierData.Text
        Sheets("Catalogue").Cells(2, 27).Value = ListBoxValue
    Unload Me
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim oCell As range
    Dim Match As range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    i = 2
    j = 0
    
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Catalogue")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set Match = ws1.Cells(2, 27)
        
    Do While ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
        Set oCell = ws2.range("A:A").Find(What:=Match)
        If Not oCell Is Nothing Then ws1.Cells(i, 2) = oCell.Offset(j, 0)
        If Not oCell Is Nothing Then ws1.Cells(i, 3) = oCell.Offset(j, 1)
        If Not oCell Is Nothing Then ws1.Cells(i, 4) = oCell.Offset(j, 9)
        i = i + 1
        j = j + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Went a different route.

```
Private Sub SupplierData_Click()
    ListBoxValue = SupplierData.Text
        Sheets("Catalogue").Cells(2, 27).Value = ListBoxValue
    Unload Me
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim oCell As range
    Dim opt3 as range
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Catalogue")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set opt3 = ws1.Cells(1, 29)
    oCell = 2
While Len(ws2.range("A" & CStr(oCell)).Value) > 0
    If ws2.Cells(oCell, 1).Value = opt3 Then
        ws1.Cells(oCell, 2).Value = ws2.Cells(oCell, 1)
        ws1.Cells(oCell, 4).Value = ws2.Cells(oCell, 2) & " " & ws2.Cells(oCell, 8) & " " & ws2.Cells(oCell, 4)
        ws1.Cells(oCell, 5).Value = ws2.Cells(oCell, 3)
        ws1.Cells(oCell, 6).Value = ws2.Cells(oCell, 10)

        oCell = oCell + 1

Wend
End Sub
```